Difference between AVR's "ADC r18, r18" and "ROL r18"
AVR has both ADC (Add with Carry) and ROL (Rotate Left through Carry) instructions.
However, it seems to me like ROL is not needed at all, and ADC r, r fulfills the same purpose.
As far as I can tell, both ADC r, r and ROL r result in (r << 1) | carry. For both, the carry is set to the MSB of the operand.
Here's an example:

r = 0x12 = 0001_0010, carry = 0

ADC r, r

r = 0010_0100 = 0x24
carry = 0


ROL r

r = 0010_0100 = 0x24
carry = 0





Intuitively, adding the register to itself is multiplying it by two, which is the same as a left-shift by one. ADC also adds the carry, which becomes the new LSB of the result.
So, what is ROL even for then? Are there any semantic differences between ROL r and ADC r, r?
I believe the same argument could be made for ROR and SBC as well.

@SepRoland yes, and that 9th bit of the numerical result is the MSB (8th bit) of the original register.

There's no difference; the docs even say rol Rd is just an alias for adc Rd,Rd, so it's the same opcode, just a convenience alias for asm source to more clearly convey the semantic meaning for human readers.
http://content.alexandria.atmel.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/GUID-61A4FA30-4426-42D7-B199-0EBF064BF9E1.html
But sbc same,same isn't a rotate right; carry propagates low to high (right to left) for both subtraction and addition.
sbc same,same is x-x - carry setting the register to 0 or -1, depending only on Carry.

Looking at a different ISA gives an interesting contrast of ISA design choices:
x86 does have a separate opcode for RCL r/m (rotate through carry) vs. ADC r, r/m.  Being a CISC machine, it allows up to one explicit memory operand for most instructions, so adc dword [ebx], [ebx] isn't encodeable so rcl dword [ebx], 1 isn't redundant.  AVR is a RISC so all computation instructions can only use register operands.
x86 also allows counts other than 1 for shifts/rotates, including runtime-variable, but those are separate opcodes from the rotate-by-implicit-1 opcode.  (Original 8086 didn't have rotate by immediate count, only 1 or CL)

excellent, thank you very much - looking at the encoding didn't cross my mind.

Incidentally, if I read correctly, x86 rcl eax, 1 also sets the overflow flag in the same way that adc eax, eax would. So they must have had this relationship in mind, since otherwise you wouldn't expect a rotate instruction to do anything particular to OF.

@NateEldredge: If you're using it for an extended-precision shift for a signed BigInt in memory or regs, the OF result has meaning for the top element.  x86 shifts-by-1 in general set OF to a well-defined value; it's probably easier to have the shift/rotate unit always work that way. (Why is the Overflow-Flag only set when single shifts are used?) Higher shift counts also change it, but to an undefined value so the actual value in that case is just an implementation detail.

@NateEldredge: I think the fact that rotates (including RCL) don't set SF, ZF, AF, or PF at all is a pretty clear sign that Steve Morse made them intentionally different from adc when architecting the 8086 ISA.  Shifts set all of those flags so even if he was anticipating a separate shift/rotate unit, he was still requiring it to produce those outputs for some right shifts.  So I think setting OF for rotates is due to the BigInt left-shift use-case directly, moreso than similarity to adc

Oh, good point. I didn't look that far down; I just assumed it was  the usual "set according to the result".

@NateEldredge: Yeah, rotates are notably inconvenient for register-renaming of FLAGS, with rotate-by-1 having to set OF but leave the rest of SPAZO unmodified.  That's why rotate by implicit 1 is 2 uops on Sandybridge-family but rotate by immediate is only 1 uop.  (I haven't checked if i8=1 decodes differently, as 2 uops.  rol r32, cl is 3 uops on Skylake, 2 uops on Ice Lake and later, but that's probably just because it has to leave FLAGS unmodified if the count is 0, another piece of x86 legacy baggage.)


So, what is ROL even for then?

It's syntactic sugar, and allows for more concise and more legible assembly code.

Are there any semantic differences between ROL r and ADC r,r ?

No.

I believe the same argument could be made for ROR and SBC as well.

No.  ROR is a "ROtate Right (register) through carry".  SBC is "SuBtract with Carry".  These are very different operations.
Though there are may other cases of shorthands / syntactic sugar:
Sugar      Resolution    Description
===================================================================
CLR  r     EOR  r,r      CLeaR all bits in register (changes SREG)
SER  d     LDI  d,0xff   SEt   all bits in d-Register
TST  r     AND  r,r      TeST register (set Z and N flag according to r)
SBR  d,m   ORI  d,m      Set   Bits in dReg (1's in mask m become 1's in d)
CBR  d,m   ANDI d,~m     Clear Bits in dReg (1's in mask m become 0's in d)
LSL  r     ADD  r,r      Logic Shift 1 bit Left.
ROL  r     ADC  r,r      ROtate Right through carry
BR** L     BRBC b,L      BRanch to L if Bit b in SREG is Clear
BR** L     BRBS b,L      BRanch to L if Bit b in SREG is Bet
The last two cases have many different aliases depending on b:
BRNE, BRCC=BRSH, BRHC, BRTC, BRIC, BRPL, ...
BREQ, BRCS=BRLO, BRHS, BRTS, BRIS, BRMI, ...

